# Map Function asking for longest route not always consistent

Tags: google-apps-script

So I've created the below function, which takes in two addresses as parameters. I am trying to return the longest recommended distance, not the shortest. Sometimes this works, sometimes this doesn't, for example:

Returning the shortest distance:
EggHead Sando Café, 519 W Capitol Expy, San Jose, CA 95136 >>>
Starbucks, 5297 Prospect Rd, San Jose, CA 95129

Wondering how to fix?

```
function getDistance (a, b) {

var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
mapObj.setOrigin(a);
mapObj.setDestination(b);
var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

 //Select longest route
var longestRoute = directions.routes.sort((a, b) => a.legs[0].distance.value > b.legs[0].distance.value ? -1 : 1)[0];

// Returns value in METERS
return longestRoute.legs[0].distance["value"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we retrieve the list of routes from the Maps API using the `getDirections` method. Next we sort the list of routes by total distance in descending order using the `Array.sort` method and a custom comparison function. The comparison function sums the distances of all the legs in each route and compares the total distances of the two routes.

```
function getDistance (a, b) {
  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(a);
  mapObj.setDestination(b);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  // Sort routes by total distance in descending order
  var sortedRoutes = directions.routes.sort((a, b) => {
    // Sum distances of all legs in each route
    var aDistance = a.legs.reduce((total, leg) => total + leg.distance.value, 0);
    var bDistance = b.legs.reduce((total, leg) => total + leg.distance.value, 0);
    return bDistance - aDistance;
  });

  // Select longest route
  var longestRoute = sortedRoutes[0];

  // Returns value in METERS
  return longestRoute.legs.reduce((total, leg) => total + leg.distance.value, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have tried these two addresses and it's still returning the shortest recommended route (18 miles versus 24 miles): Starbucks, 2410 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA 94043 >>>>> San Mateo High School, 506 N Delaware St, San Mateo, CA 94401

Comment: @Alexa - I made changes to my answer that should fix the problem.

Comment: This answer makes complete sense! However for some reason for the two addresses, it is still returning the shortest route! Is it a possible Google bug? EggHead Sando Café, 519 W Capitol Expy, San Jose, CA 95136 >>>>> Starbucks, 5297 Prospect Rd, San Jose, CA 95129

Comment: Hmmm. I would recommend logging the data out. I'm curious what the `getDirections` is sending to us. If you want to log out the data and share, I can take a look :)

Comment: The object that Google is returning is a bit difficult for me to decipher, but I tried logging sortedRoutes[0] and it did return the shortest route. However, trying to log sortedRoutes[1] and sortedRoutes[2] and it returns "null." On Google Maps, it has 3 total suggested routes, so perhaps this is where the error is occurring

Comment: Yes, so it looks like the directions object is only returning one route, even though if I look up the directions on Google Maps it returns 2 alternative routes. Looks like logging out directions.routes.length = 1